# Know who sent External Access invites

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, external-users

Is it possible to know who invited external users in SharePoint online sites, files, etc? 
Once the external account has been created, I cannot see any way to know that, unless I am missing something.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can go to **Site Settings -> Access requests and invitations -> Show History.**
Here you will see 5 columns named Person, Permission, Requested On, Status and Request For. In **Status** Column Accepted by "SomeName" will be your invitee or approver.

Comment: This could help, if I knew in which site has the external user been invited from. Checking my O365 portal I have external users but I can't go site by site checking if there has been external invitations there.

Comment: Actually, "Accepted by" refers the person that has been invited, not who sent the invitation